# How to ensure to stop async task when service is killed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I know when Androids kills a service onDestroy() is not necessarily be called (I mean really killed not stopping this service properly). I have a foreground service which  starts an async task and I have to ensure to cancel the running task when the service will be killed. The service and the async task run in the same process together with the activity being used to start the service.

My question is now how to cancel this task when I cannot rely on onDestroy() will be called? It is possible at all that Android will kill the single service and leave the process and the task running or will Android only kill the whole process? The last one would be ok for me because this will also ensure that the task stops.

Comment: If Android kills it does it thoroughly - it will kill the whole process, just killing a part inside a process is not possible.

Comment: the whole process dies. (else that wouldn't make much sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

> The Android system will attempt to keep the process hosting a service
>   around as long as the service has been started or has clients bound to
>   it. When running low on memory and needing to kill **existing
>   processes** [...]

therefore if your both AsyncTask and service share the process, both will go down.

Comment: This documentation passage seems to be the answer but according the developer guide for [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics) it seems to me that a service could be killed independently from the process: "The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus."

Answer (score 0):

You could write a test/some test code for this;

**Async Task definition**

```
doInBackground() {

  while (isHostingServiceRunning()) {
     // Do some stuff.
  }

  cancel();
}

private boolean isHostingServiceRunning() {
  final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) Application.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  final List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

  for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
    if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(<hostingServiceClassName>)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then place a debug point on the `return false` after manually stopping your service. If it gets hit then it could be argued that your task outlived your service.

I suspect the others are right (kill means kill every underlying process) but I'd be interested to know whether it's possible to orphan an async task like this.

Comment: Note that this is just test code. Don't go putting this sort of expensive checking as some sort of poll. Just find out the answer which will prob be- it's killed.

Comment: The task will outlive the service for sure. Because of that I asked the question to avoid a running orphan task. Are you sure that kill in android always stands for killing the process not only an activity or service? This means android is never able to kill a single activity or service but will always stops the underlaying process?

Comment: I can confirm the debug point was hit and the service was gone. So it does out live the ````app.Service````....